# What is the difference between snd_pcm_delay and snd_pcm_status_get_delay in ALSA?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

In a simple test application both functions return the same value. What is the difference between `snd_pcm_delay` and `snd_pcm_status_get_delay` in ALSA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snd_pcm_status()` returns multiple pieces of information; one of those is the delay.

`snd_pcm_delay()` is just a wrapper around these functions; it saves you from having to allocate the status container object.